# Existence of extremal map in teichmuller class

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry, teichmueller-theory, quasiconformal-maps

Let $R$ be a Riemann surface, and define two quasiconformal maps $f_i : R \rightarrow R_i, i=1,2$ to be equivalent if there exists a conformal map $c : R_0 \rightarrow R_1$ and a homotopy $g_t : R \rightarrow R$ through quasiconformal maps, satisfying $g_0 = \text{id}_{R}$, $g_1 = (f_1)^{-1} \circ c \circ f_0$.

Now consider $\inf_{f \in [f_1]} \log K(f)$, where $K(f) \geq 1$ is $f$'s dilatation, and $[f_1]$ is the equivalence class of the quasiconformal map $f_1 : R \rightarrow R_1$ with respect to the equivalence relation defined above.

It is a fact that $\inf_{f \in [f_1]} \log K(f) = \log K(f^{\ast})$ for some $f^{\ast} \in [f_1]$. The proof according to most sources I have been able to find is a standard argument involving normal families.

This is what I have been able to do so far:

Let us assume that $R = \tilde{R} / \Gamma$, so that $R_1 = \tilde{R} / \Gamma_0$, for some deck transformation groups $\Gamma, \Gamma_0 < \text{Aut}(\tilde{R})$ (here $\tilde{R}$ is $R$'s universal cover) and $\Gamma_0 = \tilde{f_1} \Gamma (\tilde{f_1})^{-1}$ where $\tilde{f_1} : \tilde{R} \rightarrow \tilde{R}$ is $f_1$'s quasiconformal lift.

Then wlog we may take a sequence $f_n^{\ast} \in [f_1]$, $f_n^{\ast} : \tilde{R} / \Gamma \rightarrow \tilde{R} / \Gamma_n$, where $\Gamma_n = \tilde{f_n^{\ast}} \Gamma (\tilde{f_n^{\ast}})^{-1}$, and $\tilde{f_n^{\ast}} : \tilde{R} \rightarrow \tilde{R}$ is $f_n^{\ast}$'s quasiconformal lift fixing $0,1,\infty$, such that $\log K(f_n^{\ast}) \rightarrow \inf_{f \in [f_1]} \log K(f)$.

It follows that (some subsequence of) $\tilde{f_n^{\ast}}^\rightarrow_\rightarrow \tilde{g} $ (i.e. converges uniformly to $\tilde{g}$ on compact sets), and $\tilde{g}$ descends to a quasiconformal map $g : \tilde{R} / \Gamma \rightarrow \tilde{R} / \tilde{\Gamma}$, where $\tilde{\Gamma} = \tilde{g} \Gamma (\tilde{g})^{-1}$.

Then we necessarily have $\log K(g) = \inf_{f \in [f_1]} \log K(f)$.

My issue now is I have no idea how to show that $g \in [f_1]$.

Comment: Hint: You have to use the fact that $\tilde{f}_n^*$ induces a fixed isomorphism of the groups $\Gamma, \Gamma_0$. (You mistakenly assumed that these groups are changing with $n$, also your notations are messed up.)  But this staff will be explained in any textbook on Teichmuller theory.

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry about the notation and thanks, so does it come down to showing that if $f,g$ differ by a conformal map up to homotopy, then there are lifts of each which induce the same isomorphism of $\Gamma$ (and vice versa?)

Comment: @MoisheKohan also isn't what you say only true if we assume that the limit set  of any orbit of $\Gamma$ is the real line?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming Fuchsian groups of the 1st kind. For groups of the second kind you have to be much more careful defining the Teichmuller space. The definition I know requires a different equivalence relation (so that in the case of simply connected $R$ you do not get a single point, but the universal Teichmuller space). What book are you reading?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, I think I understand how to proceed in that case. The book im reading didnt distinguish between the two at all, its “Quasiconformal Teichmuller Theory” by Gardiner and Lakic. I am supplementing it with Ahlfors short book “Lectures on quasiconformal mappings” and noticed he does make the distinction.

Comment: My suggestion is to read Lehto's book, Chapter 5: "Univalent functions and Teichmuller spaces". He is careful regarding the distinction of Fuchsian groups of 1st and 2nd kind.